# how to change values of a lot of variables quick

Tags: java

If I have a 100 boolean variables x1..x100 all set to true, how to easy and quick set them all to false without doing one at the time? Can it be done in a simple loop (for, while)?

Comment: I don't think there is a faster way to do that than simply iterate over them and change it to true.

Comment: `x1 = x2 = x3 = x4 = false;`

Comment: If you have 100 variables, you might be better off with an array instead.

Comment: use an array instead,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they're separate boolean variables, all you can do is to set them all explicitly. You can't iterate over them because they're not in an iterable structure.

```
x1 = false;
x2 = false;
// ...
x100 = false;
```

(As Elliott Frisch points out, you can shorten this to `x1 = x2 = ... = x100 = false;`, but that's not a substantial change really - aside from setting the variables in the reverse order)

But, really, you shouldn't have 100 variables like that - they're very unwieldy, and writing 100 assignments like that is error prone (you can easily miss one out, or set the same one twice by mistake).

If you use an array instead, you can set them in a loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < x.length; ++i) x[i] = false;
```

or use `Arrays.fill`:

```
Arrays.fill(x, false);
```

Alternatively, you can use a [`BitSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html), which has `set` and `clear` methods to set ranges of bits.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using [BitSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html). It has a [clear](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html#clear()) method to reset all bits to false.